# How can I run multiple ADB commands in PowerShell if && is resulting in an error?

Tags: powershell, adb

I'm importing some values from a csv file and using them to create a adb command for an Android intent with the following script. When I run the script the app opens but the message is not inputted and the key events don't appear to occur.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW '-d' "`"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$($c.number)`"" "&& ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul && adb shell input text ""$($c.Message)"" && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 22 && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 22 && adb shell input keyevent 66"
```

If I output the script to the screen and copy and paste the output into a cmd window then everything works as expected. If if I do the same into PowerShell I get the error

> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

How can I amend this script to work in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

I addressed the issue by separating the chained adb commands into individual commands and replaced the ping with Start-seep. It works but there is probably a more efficient solution.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW '-d' "`"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$($c.number)`""

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepType
            
            adb shell input text ""$($c.Message)""

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepPress
            
            adb shell input keyevent 22

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepPress
            
            adb shell input keyevent 22

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepPress
            
            adb shell input keyevent 22

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepPress
            
            adb shell input keyevent 22

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepPress
            
            adb shell input keyevent 66
```